# Minimum OS version incorrect

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I've got my deployment target set to iOS 4.0 and yet when it's all compile the value is 3.1. WTF?

Anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings like this can be set in multiple places. Check that your target setting is correct: it'll override the project setting.

Comment: You sir, are my hero. That was so fast stack overflow won't allow me to accept your answer for another five minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Application settings can be set on the project (typically the blue icon at the top of your Xcode drawer) but also can be overridden in individual application Targets (the little red bullseye icon). Settings applied to the project are kind of like global settings. You can change the global settings in different targets though. So check that you're not setting 3.1 in a target thus overriding your Project settings which you have set to 4.0.

Comment: Sorry man, had to give it to the other guy cause he was first. I went ahead and gave you an up vote though. Cheers!

Comment: Noooo! But mine was longer! ;) Thanks, appreciate the props.